# Unable to Retrieve User Data from MongoDB Using Mongoose and Express

Tags: mongoose, postman, backend, mern, web-development-server

I'm developing a Node.js application using Express and MongoDB with Mongoose. In my application, I have a route for user registration that involves checking if a user exists in the database. However, when I send a POST request to the /auth/register endpoint using Postman, I consistently receive null as the response, indicating that the user is not found.

I have ensured the following:

My MongoDB connection is established correctly.
The data in my MongoDB database is as expected.

index.js

```
app.use('/auth',userRouter);
/* Connect to our database */
mongoose.connect("mongodb+srv://Choudhary_Himanshu:R22dias@recipes.3i1bpj2.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority", 
{ useNewUrlParser: true,useUnifiedTopology:true })
```

Users.js

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const user_schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    password: { type: String, required: true }
});

export const User_model = mongoose.model("users", user_schema);
```

user.js

```
import express from 'express';
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';
import bcrypt from 'bcrypt';
import { User_model } from '../Models/Users.js';

const router = express.Router(); 
router.post('/register', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const { username, password } = req.body;
        const user = await User_model.findOne({ username: username, password: password });
        res.json(user);
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.log(err.message);
    }
});

export { router as userRouter };
```